# How to generate WSDL for web service returning XMLDocument

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, xmldocument

I have a WebMethod returning a XMLDocument to export data to an external system. This is all fine, but the external system is trying to access the WSDL of the response to import the XML information (nullable types, etc).

When they look at the WSDL it doesn't give any details regarding the XML format, probably because the XML is dynamically generated.

So my question is, is it possible to generate a useful WSDL for a webservice method returning a dynamically generated XMLDocument?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [SoapHttpClientProtocol.Discover Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.discover(v=vs.110).aspx)

please ref msdn samples.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that looks like something that the client is invoking. I need to be making changes on the server side...